# Parsing JSON files with arrays in Go

Tags: json, go

The following is the JSON file I'm trying to parse (OpenWeatherMap API if anyone is curious). The builtin `encoding/json` does a pretty good job of it. When I use `json.Unmarshal(testJson, &parsed)`, most of the JSON file is parsed correctly. However, with the way that it is formatted, the "weather" is giving me a headache.

I parsed the file generated by `encoding/json` with `parsedMap := parsed.(map[string]interface{})`, which works when I try to refer to key,value pair with the key "main".

With `fmt.Println()`, the value is `map[temp:280.32 pressure:1012 humidity:81 temp_min:279.15 temp_max:281.15]`, which I can work with.

With the key "weather" however, I get this `[map[icon:09d id:300 main:Drizzle description:light intensity drizzle]]`. The additional square brackets seem to be causing issues.

```
{
  "coord": {
      "lon": -0.13,
      "lat": 51.51
    },
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 300,
        "main": "Drizzle",
        "description": "light intensity drizzle",
        "icon": "09d"
      }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
      "temp": 280.32,
      "pressure": 1012,
      "humidity": 81,
      "temp_min": 279.15,
      "temp_max": 281.15
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.1,
      "deg": 80
    },
    "clouds": {
      "all": 90
    },
    "dt": 1485789600,
    "sys": {
      "type": 1,
      "id": 5091,
      "message": 0.0103,
      "country": "GB",
      "sunrise": 1485762037,
      "sunset": 1485794875
    },
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "cod": 200
  }
```

Code for reference:

var testJSON = //JSON EARLIER IN THE POST
    var parsed interface{}

```
json.Unmarshal(testJSON, &parsed)

parsedMap := parsed.(map[string]interface{})
mainTemp := parsedMap["weather"]


fmt.Println(mainTemp)
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem in fact; why did you want help ?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour: If it were any different, `json.Unmarshal` would not be able to handle 1-length slices, such as the one you are using in your JSON.

Comment: @NatNgs Basically I just need help "removing the square brackets" from it. When I tried to refer to it as an array (referring to index 0), it didn't work

Comment: @NatNgs It threw an error saying "invalid operation: mainTemp[0] (type interface {} does not support indexing)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first perform a Type assertions on weather as an array of interface{}.

Then do the same on the first element as a map[string]interface{}

```
temps := parsedMap["weather"].([]interface{})
mainTemp := temps[0].(map[string]interface{})
```

You can see a full example here https://play.golang.org/p/JIfCGrsYl9

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to cast as a `[]interface{}`.

However, you should have a look at using [JSON to Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to easily generate a struct type for the JSON you expect. You can strip out any fields you're not interested in.

Saves a lot of type-casting (and error checking)!